# Azure DevOps organization management - one large project?

Tags: azure-devops

**Context**

I'm managing an Azure DevOps organization that is intended for an entire global department, where several types of teams work and collaborate together. The entire use case is similar to internal customer support (there are Requesters needing something and Agents doing the work), for which we mostly use Azure Boards (and Repos for Wiki, but we don't use any Azure automation, pipelines and such).

**Current structure**

- 4 process templates - I believe I can base all projects on a single
  master template, though
- 2 projects on each template

**Idea**

Consolidate all the projects into a single project. However, I am somewhat afraid of performance and cannot find good resources confirming (or not) if the platform can take large traffic.

**Current traffic**

- 7 projects
- 10k work items weekly, largest project produces 4k work items weekly
- 1700 users
- ~100 teams

**Question:**

Does anyone have experience with running one large project with such traffic?
The total size of our userbase is not that big - it's 200 so-called agents and probably 1500 requesters. These numbers will grow over time.

One thing that would be impacted for sure is queries, as now we're querying from those 4k items weekly, but in a one master project it would be each query looking initially into 10k weekly items.
One potential mitigation of this is archiving some work items to a separate project every, say, 3-5 months.

Ok, enough data. If anyone can share their five cents, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

> Azure DevOps organization management - one large project?

This is a matter of taste selection.

Accoring to your Current traffic:

- 10k work items weekly, largest project produces 4k work items weekly
- 1700 users
- ~100 teams

Personal experience does not recommend consolidating all the projects into a single project.

Consolidating all the projects into a single project helps us see all workitems on one boards. However, since you have more work items, this reduces the efficiency of query and management.

Azure devops also [limits the results of the query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/object-limits?view=azure-devops#work-items-and-queries)：

[image]